# Reinstalling Gimp 2.8 into 20.04

Tags: software-installation, gimp

I recently was upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...I have mixed feelings about it, but I'm willing to work with it...it's not bad, just slow at times.
I thought I would enjoy the upgrade to GIMP 2.10.  I was wrong.  I dislike too much about it. I don't like how the filters run, I don't like how certain tools perform, I don't like that I can't run certain scripts, so, I'm kinda done with it.  It has to go.

I would very much like to go back to GIMP 2.8...any version, to be honest.  I have tried installing the stable version of 2.8 from Gimp's website, and after the hoop-jumping to install flatpak, I found out that it installed an *EVEN WORSE* version of 2.10., which was quickly uninstalled.

I tried looking all over to find out how to get 2.8 reinstalled...looked up installing through snapcraft...nope.  Ubuntu's Software Center? Nay-nay. How about Otto Kesselgulasch's version?  Big-time NO.  I would build from source, but I have no idea where to start, or what to do.

How in the world can I get 2.8 working on my system? Sorry for the rant disguised as a question.  Please keep any answers *SIMPLE*.  I'm not a technomancer, so I would really appreciate even a technical answer to be *UNDERSTANDABLE.*

Many thanks

-M-

Comment: Try this: https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.8/gimp-2.8.22.tar.bz2

Comment: There is an AppImage here: http://files.dantas.airpost.net/public/GIMP2.8-glibc2.17-x86_64.AppImage This worked well on my system but I do not know the packager or his credentials...

Comment: CMake (using the GUI.  See above disclaimer) tells me the .tar.bz2 file is missing "CMakeLists.txt"  I tried copying and pasting it from another folder, and it started to configure and then gave me an error.  Apparently the .txt file is unique to each(?) and I'm stuck for now.

Comment: Eschewed the CMake route and went with the directions I saw here: https://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/  Everything was going ok, until I hit a wall with GEGL 0.2  I looked in Synaptic and all I saw was 0.4 and some other gegl-type files whose purpose and function I can only guess at.

Comment: To build a Gimp 2.8 you need also a bunch of other packages, especially Gegl at version 0.2.0 and Babl at version 0.1.26. This eventually compiles on my 19.10. From 20.04 onwards, things get a bit complicated because Gimp still uses Python v2 and this isn't installed by default on Ubuntu 20+ (but can be part of flatpak/appimage). This said, Gimp 2.10 is a huge leap forward from 2.8 (high image precision, and much more interactive tools) so sticking to 2.8 is a bad idea (every version introduces UI changes, remember the Save/export controversy between 2.6 and 2.8...).

Comment: I realize I might just be beating my head against a wall.  Maybe I should just deal with 2.10 warts and all.  This may just be coming from a place of frustration with my old scripts not working. (Which I know is another thread unto itself.)  I wouldn't say that you (xenoid) have sold me entirely on 2.10, but you have me at least looking at it in a slightly different light.  If you're referring to Gimp saving files as .xcf and having to export as other file types, I wouldn't think of that too much as a controversy as much as a jarring change.  Thanks again.

Comment: Still not keen on how the solid noise & difference cloud filters work.

Comment: For me these are why I don't want 2.10: https://askubuntu.com/q/1326072/1157519 and especially https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/146854 . I know people like to explain things easily with change aversion, but these two issues make 2.10 a serious step backwards for me; I feel so even after being forced to use it for half a year: it's not about the question of just getting used to it. These features have really degraded. I just want 2.8 back so bad. It was a really-really nice tool to use!

Answer (score 1):

install an old Mint 18.3 on a new partition and just use its GIMP 2.8.16 on your files. I upgraded to the latest Mint and hated the GIMP 2.10 as I lost my  iwarp feature I use on fender flares on car pictures. Tried in vain to extract the GIMP 2.8 off a Linux STUDIO disk I had and all the online varients but kept running into the same version check roadblocks. I'm happy with the 2.8.16 and will continue to use it as is. Throw all your pictures on a SD card and just work off that so as to make portability between versions easy.