# How could I add Gimp 2.8's UI theme to Gimp 2.10?

Tags: themes, gimp

I'm using the deb-installed variant of Gimp 2.10.18 on stock Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3 desktop.

Gimp 2.10 offers majorly revamped themes (There are now `Dark`, `Grey`, `Light`, and `System`). I struggle to find them either useful or usable. I can't perceive the end-result in these new themes, so I can't know where I stand with editing until I export and open the image in its final target context (where I want to present it).

This slows me down immensely. Yesterday I edited 3 landscape photos throughout 10 hours! I also have doubts that I could reach the best possible results throughout all this struggling.

Could I add Gimp 2.8's familiar, proven-to-be-productive default theme to Gimp 2.10?

(Note: I have already found and use the `Legacy` *icon theme*, which is nice. The challenge that I'm facing is with the background color of windows and various graphs.)

Comment: Is ist just the theme you are struggling with, i.e. appearance of the icons? There are also icon themes you can change, including "color" and "legacy".

Comment: @vanadium yes, thank you, I have already found and use the Legacy icon theme. I will edit my question.

Comment: Still not clear what is your issue if it is the background color and the looks. You can have Gimp adopt your default system theme settings.

Comment: @vanadium Choosing the `System` theme yields a background color of `#f5f6f7`, which is (not very bad, but) not a neutral gray and I was afraid that it may influence my judgement of color temperature. Additionally, I have no idea where that value is coming from; I use the Yaru Light theme, and in screenshots of a few GUI windows (e.g. gnome-control-center and Nautilus) I could not find this BG color. So I don't know where in the "system" it is derived from. So I was not eager to choose a less-than-perfect value that I felt might change on a whim in the future beyond my control.

Comment: I have came across a firm point against using the `System` theme un-altered: the _Color balance_ dialog has three range widgets, representing three axes of the color space: Cyan vs Red, Magenta vs Green and Yellow vs Blue. The current values are shown by bars filled with solid color: the **highly saturated Ubuntu brand orange**. Putting bright orange there entirely short-circuits the part of my brain that should model and imagine color-space manipulations. It's like staring perplexedly, while the mind is stuck in a deadlock. _Seeing the orange there undoes thinking about the other colors._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gimp themes are defined in `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/${ThemeName}/`.

The most important part of the theme is the `gtkrc` file.

There are very few differences between the 2.08 `Default` and the 2.10 `System` themes (none of these defines any color).

If your problem is mostly a matter of colors, you can copy any of the non-`System` themes and edit the `gtkrc` file to define your own colors (some strategic colors are defined at the top).

Comment: My current last comment shows another reason why I might not wish to build on the System theme. So I have looked up the "Light" theme's gtkrc in 2.10: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/blob/gimp-2-10/themes/Light/gtkrc I can see color definitions in there. By any chance, could you help me by pointing to which definition might be responsible for the window backgrounds? Or is there a reference guide for this?

Comment: Brilliant, so far I have copied "Light" to "Mytheme" and I can enable it in the Preferences. Now I only need to figure out what to modify.

Comment: A screen shot of my Gimp (I use the "Light" theme) shows that the background color is `(221,221,221)` in other words `#DDDDDD` which is the definition of `clr4` and `clr8`  at the beginning of the file (it is also used in `kde_hack` styles but if you don't use KDE/Plasma this is possibly irrelevant.

Comment: Right, that also worked. Thank you! (Yeah, I had to do `kde_hack_2` and `kde_hack_3` too.)

Comment: Wow, both you and I have the `gtk_hack_` bits, but in the latest state of the file (linked in my first comment), they are not there any more. I have found [where they were added](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/commit/6e109052ca8c431644ce6e75693d7865cd2f1673#2e9e0c6c9a6bd60f633042596627746ba54185a3_0_116), and [where they were removed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/commit/3198d2778748469a84eb87c0a5ce848bf1877fc1#776ec5efe7cc5c59b8865541f78b5f908b945488_116_0). Both of these events were 5 years ago (2016 Jan / Feb) :O

Comment: Just for those who would want to try this out on a `flatpak` variant (much more recent version is available (at the time of writing): `2.10.24`), copying and modifying the theme works the same way. The themes are here: `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable/<long-randomized-string>/files/share/gimp/2.0/themes/`